# cant seem to get validate email to work in php

Tags: php, html

I followed a guide for this but mine doesnt work unlike the guide. When i add a valid email into my form input field its still saying that the email is invalid... all my other code for validations are working besides the email, here is my code. Any help would be great.

Ive tried one solution that i found on here and that was to change

```
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $email_error = "Invalid email format";
        }
```

To

```
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $email_error = "Invalid email format";
        }
```

That fixed the error to where i could enter an email in but soon i found out that it didnt even need to be an email, i could put whatever i wanted in the input field. so back to my original question, am i missing something?

```
<?php

$firstName_error = $lastName_error = $email_error = "";
$firstname = $lastname = $email = $subject = $message = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
        $firstName_error = "First name is required";
    } else {
        $firstName = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname)) {
            $firstName_error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["lastname"])) {
        $lastName_error = "Last name is required";
    } else {
        $lastName = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastname)) {
            $lastName_error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }
    
    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $email_error = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $email_error = "Invalid email format";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $message = "";
    } else {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
}
```

And here is the HTML

```
            <div class="container contact-form">
              <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="input50">
                      <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?= $firstname ?>" />
                      <span class="error"><?= $firstName_error ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input50">
                      <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?= $lastname ?>" />
                      <span class="error"><?= $lastName_error ?></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="input50">
                      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?= $email ?>" />
                      <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input50">
                      <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" value="<?= $subject ?>" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="input100">
                      <textarea type="text" placeholder="Message" name="message"value="<?= $message ?>"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="input100">
                      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </form>
              <div class="contact-map" id='map'></div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: I assume that your `test_input` is messing with the `@` in your email as soon as it passes through `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: thanks for the reply! @GuidoFaecke for the purpose of the test i got rid of the `htmlspecialchars` and it still doenst work

Comment: Try to compare the results of `var_dump(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` against `var_dump($email)`. That might shed some light on it.